# Difference in value from SQL Server to C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm converting this formula here to a C# code:

```
declare @decPorcDescuentoTotal DECIMAL(18, 5), @decImporteCuota DECIMAL(18, 5), @decImporteSA DECIMAL(18, 5), @intCantCuotas INT

set @decImporteCuota = 65.20091
set @decImporteSA = 1820.76533
set @intCantCuotas = 26
set @decPorcDescuentoTotal = 100 * (1 - (@decImporteCuota * CAST(26 AS int)) / @decImporteSA)

select @decPorcDescuentoTotal
```

Resultado = 6.89500

But if instead of `CAST(26 AS int)` I put 26 it returns:

Resultado = 6.89499

I need to get the first result using C# but when I multiply it by 26 it returns the second result.

Comment: You just need to round to 3 decimal places... which is what SQL Server is doing implicitly.

Comment: What does your C# code looks like? It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing your code

Comment: If those numbers are exact, then the result (according to Windows Calculator - which has arbitrarily large precision) is `6.894994535072787221843684820163`.  Excel says it's `6.894994535`.  If you want it rounded to `6.895`, then do that.  Realize that  `6.895` is a correct answer.  As is `6.894994535`.  However, `6.89500` is not

Comment: Post your C# code too. It could help the community to understand better your problem.